# Python - two-dimensional array adressing fills up the whole array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a problem. First let me show you the code:

```
def neon(l):
    oc = 0; #naj ocena
    tz = 0; #teraz ocena

    #sprawdzanie poziomo
    for x in range(len(l[0])):
        for i in range(len(l[x])):
            for y in range(i + 1,len(l[x])):
                tz = l[x][i] + l[x][y] + (max(y - x, x - y) + 1) * 2;
                if (tz > oc):
                    oc = tz;

    pion = [[0] * len(l[0])] * len(l);

    print(pion);
    print("#######");

    for i in range(len(pion)):
        for y in range(len(pion[i])):
            pion[i][y] = l[y][i];

        print(pion);

neon([[1,2,1,2],[7,1,7,1],[1,1,1,1],[3,3,3,3]]);
```

The problem is that when i try to adress `pion[i][y]` instead of just changing that value from 0 to whatever the program changes the value in all of the inner arrays with the second index y. This is how it looks:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
#######
[[1, 7, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3]]
[[2, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3]]
[[1, 7, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3]]
[[2, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3]]
```

Instead, it should be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
#######
[[1, 7, 1, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 7, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 7, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1, 7, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3], [1, 7, 1, 3], [2, 1, 1, 3]]
```

Please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs due to the following reasons:

1. `pion`is a list of inner lists. Each element of pion just holds the reference to one inner list.
2. Because of the way you have created and initialized `pion` (using `pion = [[0] * len(l[0])] * len(l)`), all elements of `pion` hold references **to the same inner list**. So, in `pion`, instead of many distinct inner lists, you just have multiple references to a single inner list. In other words, `pion[0]`, `pion[1]`, `pion[2]`, etc, are all references to the same inner list of zeros. Any modification that you make to this inner list, using a particular row index (eg, using the expression `pion[3]`), will be visible through all the other row indexes also, because, at all row indexes, you are just holding a reference to the same inner list.

To correct this, you need to create and initialize the list differently. Eg, if `rows` and `cols` are respectively the number of rows and columns, you could do something like this:

```
pion = [([0]*cols) for i in range(rows)]
```

Comment: @AdamSołtan: I have updated my answer showing how to do that.